# import a file from another location - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, python-import

There are two folders , each contain a python file . 
For example: first_folder contains a.py & second_folder contains b.py

I tried importing b.py in a.py
But i got not Import error.

**ImportError: No module named b**

Pls help me to solve this. I also tried creating a blank **init**.py in both folders, but it did not worked.

**Folder structure:**

/home/user/scripts/

```
 |
 |--------python_scripts
 |          |
 |          |
 |          |------- a.py
 |
 |--------lib
           |
           |-------b.py
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of your folder structure?

Comment: Probably these two files are not in the PATH or your working directory is not at the correct location.

Comment: What is your folder structure and what files do you have in which folders?

Comment: first folder :'python_script' that contains a.py
2nd folder : ' lib ' that contains b.py
Both folders are in same location. I am running the scripts one folder behind the location

Comment: For example:
'scripts ' folder contains ' python_script '  and ' lib' folder.
i am executing in 'scripts'  location

Comment: provide sample directory structure, helping you is very limited in this perspective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's `import` is going to look for the modules (`.py` files) in the python path. You can see what is in python path in the [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) variable.

By default, [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) will include directory where the script you ran is located. It will also include everything defined in the [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable.

So, if you have two directories with `.py` files, you can either put both in python path, or you can make sure everything all of your source is under the same path entry.

### Option 1

(this syntax depends on your shell, here it is for windows)

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;\path\to\second_folder

python \path\to\first_folder\a.py
```

Then, you can simply `import b`.

### Option 2

Create an empty `__init__.py` in both directories and a `run.py` in the directory above them, so you have:

```
root_dir
    run.py
    first_folder
        __init__.py
        a.py
    sedond_folder
        __init__.py
        b.py
```

Make `run.py` your entry point (run `python run.py`) and then you can import any of the modules from any other module using their full module names:

```
import first_folder.a
import second_folder.b
```

Comment: Thanks. with appending a folder to  'sys.path' it worked

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have files like this

```
.
├── first_folder
│   └── a.py
└── second_folder
    └── b.py
```

You can use abs path to import `a.py` as a module in `b.py`

```
import importlib.util

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('a', 'path/to/first_folder/a.py')

foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)

spec.loader.exec_module(foo)

print(dir(foo))
```

There is another convenient way to load `b.py`

$ cd path/to/second_folder

```
$ ln -s path/to/first_folder ./first_folder
```

and import `a.py` as a normal python module

```
import a from first_folder
```

Answer (score 0):

If the files are in the same directory type this

```
Import .other_file
```

Comment: files are in different directory

Comment: It really depends on how it’s laid out as to what you have to do. Could you provide the exact file structure? Also it might help to work with pycharm. It will help you write better code